# How do I replace to_json in Ruby with the Oj gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activesupport

Ruby's to_json is incredibly slow.  I want to use the Oj gem, replacing the to_json implementation.  I added oj and oj_mimic_json, but that appears only to affect ActiveSupport's `ActiveSupport::JSON`

```
require 'oj'
require 'oj_mimic_json'
```

Is there a canonical way to replace to_json with a different backend, like Oj?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out: [MultiJson gem](https://github.com/intridea/multi_json)
It'll use oj as default json parser by default in compat mode (compatibility)